# New to Python 3.4+ Scripting and Manipulating JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm currently trying to manipulate JSON with a script that I've wrote.  And it is doing what I want it to do, but there's something needed to be adjust, and that is to change the Class? of the JSON? not sure if that's what is called in JSON.

```
"rooms": {
    "1": {
        "tiles": {
            "-3,1": {
                "x": -4,
                "scaleY": 1,
                "scaleX": 1,
                "y": 1,
                "id": "58"
            },
            "-2,-3": {
                "x": -3,
                "scaleY": 1,
                "scaleX": 1,
                "y": -3,
                "id": "193"
            },
            "5,-3": {
                "x": 6,
                "scaleY": 1,
                "scaleX": 1,
                "y": -3,
                "id": "58"
            },
            "0,-11": {
                "x": -1,
                "scaleY": 1,
                "scaleX": 1,
                "y": -11,
                "id": "55"
            }
          }
          }
```

These are just a snip bits of the JSON there are way more than these

I'd like to change the "-3,1" to "-4,1", I want all the "x" and "y" match the class.

like "-2,-3" to "-3,-3" ,  "5,-3" to "6,-3"   ,   "-1,-11"

And I'm not sure on how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your JSON string into a python object using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), then you can update the inner dict at key `tiles` like so:

```
d = {"rooms": {
         "1": {
             "tiles": {
                "-3,1": {
                    "x": -4,
                    "scaleY": 1,
                    "scaleX": 1,
                    "y": 1,
                    "id": "58"
                },
                "-2,-3": {
                    "x": -3,
                    "scaleY": 1,
                    "scaleX": 1,
                    "y": -3,
                    "id": "193"
                },
                "5,-3": {
                    "x": 6,
                    "scaleY": 1,
                    "scaleX": 1,
                    "y": -3,
                    "id": "58"
                },
                "0,-11": {
                    "x": -1,
                    "scaleY": 1,
                    "scaleX": 1,
                    "y": -11,
                    "id": "55"
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
b = {}
for k, v in d['rooms']['1']['tiles'].items(): 
    b['{},{}'.format(v['x'], v['y'])] = v
d['rooms']['1']['tiles'] = b
```

This works for the sample you have posted. For your data, you may need to consider multiple keys in the main dictionary. Using `.items()` to do this is one of the possibilities.